# Idiomatic way to write tests in an inner scope

Tags: rust, rust-macros

I understand that I can test top-level functions like so:

```rust
#[test]
fn test() {
    assert_eq!(1 + 2, 3);
}
```

However, this does not work for inner functions, i.e. like so:

```rust
fn outer() {

    #[test]
    fn inner() {}
}
```

My motivation is to generate a test for expression-like macro invocations, as static checks could (in my case) get quite expensive and I don't want to wait ages for compilation.

Concretely, I have SQL queries I would like to test (such that I can be sure the schema works & there are no syntax errors)
But I don't want to have the database running all the time during compilation and I think it would be quite slow.

Example:

```rust
let query = sql!("SELECT * FROM PERSON WHERE AGE > 30");
```

Ideally I would just like to run each such query in a test function as well, but I can't insert that in the middle of an existing function.

I have considered writing a macro to be put in module scope that somehow reads the whole source code and then generates the tests there, but that seems like quite the hack to me.

Is there a clean way to achieve this?

Comment: "My motivation is to generate a test for expression-like macro invocations", can't you create normal integration/unit tests where you invoke your macro and then test its side-effects/the code it generated? I don't think tests are a good way to replace static checks in your code. If you worry about the cost of your checks, there is the [`debug_assert!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.debug_assert.html) macro which only runs the check in debug mode, not in release mode

Comment: Could you give an example of your motivation? I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: I updated the question to include my specific needs.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you want the inner tests to exist inside an outer function? You should be aware, if you're not already, that `fn inner` is *not* a closure, and doesn't capture variables from the parent scope.